# Are JavaScript variables a reference, value or pointer

Tags: javascript, pointers, queryselector

A search didn't quite get me the answer I was looking for.

I am curious if setting a variable to a queryselector is a reference, pointer or value.

Example 1:

```
// lets assume there is only one ".class"
var element = document.queryselector(".class");

element.classList.remove("effect1");
element.classList.add("effect2");
```

Example 2:

```
document.queryselector(".class").classList.remove("effect1");
document.queryselector(".class").classList.add("effect2");
```

Are these exactly the same thing? Or by setting the variable to the selector, are you saving overhead?

My thought is that if the variable is a value, then the query selector won't search the DOM when the variable is used.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript objects are always passed by reference so both examples have the same effect since `document.querySelector` returns a DOM Element (which is an object).

As a short FYI:

- Primitive types are always passed by value
- Arrays are also passed by reference

Your first example is much more efficient because you only have to search the DOM once and there is absolutely no difference in their effect.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is always **pass by value**, but when a variable refers to an object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object.

```
var element = document.queryselector(".class"); // element is an object
```

So both examples are exactly the same. Under the hood is just accessing classList property of element object.

Yes, first code snippet is efficient because we are saving a cycle to fetch DOM nodes again. If we are just accessing dom element nodes a few times let say 10-100 (normally in a mid to large project) then the performance won't be impacted much. I mean you can just ignore that. That won't be a drastic effect.
But yes if we are accessing dom nodes a million times then that effect is noticeable.
Let's check for 1 million times, just to access DOM element nodes.

```
first = performance.now();
new Array(1000000).fill(1).forEach(() => {
    div = document.querySelector('div');
})
second = performance.now();
console.log(`${second - first} milliseconds`);   //337.2850000159815 milliseconds
// Result can alter from machine to machine
```

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I know they are functional the same. My question is in regards to overhead/efficiency. If an object is returned, then example one should be more efficient..

Comment: I like that you created a test. I was thinking of doing something similar. I am not sure this is accurate of a real world situation though. There is no document hierarchy in this test. And the complexity of the selector could have a pretty substantial impact. If there is only one div on the page, accessing it X number of times requires, effectively, 0 traversing. And that is probably where the best practice shines.